# nodejs cloudflare ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ssl-certificate, cloud

When I build my site with ssl on cloudflare my site works clearly
but in nodejs ws server i change with wss server 
and read key and pem files on nodejs 
I got an error console like this ERR_CERRT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

how can i fix this error? Any idea?

Notes: my wss server port is :8443

I try cloudflare ssl optiond flexible, full and full (stricth)

My app is live chat script coded with nodejs

Here is the code:

```
var https = require('https'); 
var fs = require('fs'); 
var webSocketsServerPort = 8443; 
var webSocketServer = require('websocket').server; 
var options = { key: fs.readFileSync('key.key'), cert: fs.readFileSync('x.pem') }; 
var server = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) { 

res.writeHead(200); 
res.end("deneme\n"); 
}).listen(webSocketsServerPort); 
server.listen(webSocketsServerPort, function () { 
console.log((new Date()) + " server geldi " + webSocketsServerPort); 
}); 
var wsServer = new webSocketServer({ httpServer: server });
```

Comment: Can .you include the code of your nodejs ws server

Comment: @LucasHendren var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var webSocketsServerPort = 8443;
var webSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('x.pem')
};
var server = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("deneme\n");
}).listen(webSocketsServerPort);
server.listen(webSocketsServerPort, function () {
    console.log((new Date()) + " server geldi " +
        webSocketsServerPort);
});
var wsServer = new webSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

Comment: @SametAras it looks like Lucas was kind enough to edit the question with your code in it, but in the future you should add the code *into the question*, not as a comment.  You can edit your question to add the code in the relevant code blocks if you have code to add.